# Configure the width of fact-set items in ms teams bot response

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am using factset in bot response to show columns as shown in the screenshot below...
[image]

When the value of a fact increases a certain length, the first column adjusts itself making  the "updated" go into the next line..
[image]

Is there any way to avoid this? I want the "Last update" in all cases to be in the same line...

Comment: Add your adaptive card json file in your question.

Comment: I have verified your content in adaptive card designer and this is a limitation in ms team UI. Because MS team align the UI automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any property associated with FactSet or Fact to handle width.

What you can try is to make your AdaptiveCard : [Full width](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#full-width-adaptive-card) this might solve your problem (not 100% but if text contains in full width).

You can also try using [ColumnSet](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/ColumnSet.html) as Column has a width properties.

I tried your scenario using Columns and it is rendering fine. Have look at my AdaptiveCard JSON and its output below.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.2",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "100px",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Author",
                                    "wrap": true,
                                    "weight": "Bolder"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Last Updated",
                                    "wrap": true,
                                    "weight": "Bolder"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Tickers",
                                    "wrap": true,
                                    "weight": "Bolder"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Tags",
                                    "wrap": true,
                                    "weight": "Bolder"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Matt Hidinger"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Created {{DATE(2017-02-14T06:08:39Z, SHORT)}}",
                                    "wrap": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "#5 Some VALUE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "#someTags  #someTags#someTags#someTags#so someTags#someTags #someTags#someTags#someTags#someTags #someTags#someTags #someTags #someTags #someTags #someTags #someTags #someTags",
                                    "wrap": true
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Result look like this:

[image]

Comment: But i am facing an issue with this json, when i tried putting "" (empty string ) as value against tickers, i got unexpected result.

Comment: Is this what you are seeing?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaqfo.png

Comment: I am looking for something but probably I need to raise an internal bug.

Comment: Hello @Neha Singla,
So for FactSet it is by design and you cannot maintain its width. We have raised a bug for the behavior that you shared for ColumnSet when TextBlock text is empty. I don't have an ETA to share but I will update you once it is fixed. Meanwhile the workaround could be to show _"-"_ in place of empty string.

Comment: Update from internal Team on the bug raised- The rows in the two columns don't necessarily snap to align like table. The rows in ColumnSet grow/shrink independently.

So it is by design. You might need to give `-` in place of empty string.